# How do I speed up this cursor in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop, database-cursor

Can someone help me with this T-SQL cursor? Do I even need a cursor in this scenario? Essentially, for every iteration of `inventoryID`, it runs a separate query. Is there a way to speed this up because it is way too slow? Thanks for your help!

```
DECLARE @MyCursor CURSOR;
DECLARE @invID BIGINT;

BEGIN

    SET @MyCursor = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT RecordID
    FROM [Derived].[AllInventory];

    OPEN @MyCursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
    INTO @invID;

    WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [Derived].[Allocation]
        SELECT TOP (1)
               @invID
              ,i.InventoryType
              ,i.ProductCode
              ,i.ProductionDate
              ,o.OrderID
              ,o.MinProductionDate
              ,o.ShipDate
              ,o.OrdRank
              ,o.BalanceCode
        FROM [Derived].[AllInventory] i
            CROSS APPLY (
                            SELECT *
                            FROM [Derived].[Orders] o
                            WHERE (
                                      i.InventoryType = 'Current'
                                      AND CAST(i.ProductCode AS NVARCHAR(50)) = CAST(o.ProductCode AS NVARCHAR(50))
                                      OR i.InventoryType = 'Future'
                                         AND CAST(i.ProductCode AS NVARCHAR(50)) = CAST(o.BalanceCode AS NVARCHAR(50))
                                  )
                                  AND i.ProductionDate >= o.MinProductionDate
                                  AND o.OrderID NOT IN (
                                                           SELECT OrdId
                                                           FROM [Derived].[Allocation]
                                                       )
                        ) o;

        FETCH NEXT FROM @MyCursor
        INTO @invID;
    END;

    CLOSE @MyCursor;
    DEALLOCATE @MyCursor;
END;

SELECT *
FROM [Derived].[Allocation];
```

Comment: It's exactly as you say: get rid of the cursor, and enjoy an enormous performance boost!

Comment: Use of TOP 1 and cross apply suggest a logic flaw. Use of TOP without an ORDER BY clause is usually logic flaw as well. You want one row but you don't care which row? Mixing the use of AND and OR in a filter is tricky to do correctly without parentheses. Are you certain about the effect of that lack? Casting of columns is another concern - that can prevent the use of indexes that might be helpful. I can see other issues - but simply removing the cursor is the logical first step.

Comment: Yes.  I would expect `@invID` to be used in the WHERE clause of the query inside the loop.  And wrapping the whole loop in a transaction will avoid a log file flush for each row.

Comment: There are so many questions that need answering before people can really help you, and these can likely be answered by including the following in your question: sample input data and your expected output based on that data, what you are actually trying to achieve (it looks like you are trying to match orders to inventory items but make that clear in your question - you have included what you have tried which is good).

Comment: what is the datatype of ProductCode? those `CAST`s cant be helping and may not be required.

Comment: Basically, I have two views which breaks out orders and inventory into individual boxes for which I put a inventoryID and orderID field. ProductCode is nvarchar because there's sometimes funky ones they create. I need to attach every order id to inventory order if compatitble (meaning product code match and inventory production date is greater than orders MinProductionDate. I've tried removing cursor and using a while exists loop but it's just as slow...thanks everyone for help/